# Charting two data sets; one begins where the other ends

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm working on building a retirement model currently that predicts the value of one's portfolio as they draw income from it. I have used a named range up to this point to show how their portfolio grows from year to year, however, I would like to now append another data set when this one finishes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some example data or details of what you've already tried would be helpful to people wanting to answer your question.

Comment: Use an XY/Scatter chart with the dates as your horizontal axis.  This will allow you to run your data sets however you like, while maintaining their chronological position correctly.